# kubeadm join fails with connection refused on one node only

Tags: join, kubernetes, kubeadm

I have a Kubernetes cluster with 1 master and 5 workers,
when I try to join the 6th worker node, It gets this error:

```
$ sudo kubeadm join 172.22.20.20:6443 --token xxxxx.yyyyyyyy --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:zzzzzzz
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
    [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
Suggestion: go get github.com/kubernetes-incubator/cri-tools/cmd/crictl
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "172.22.20.20:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://172.22.20.20:6443"
[discovery] Failed to request cluster info, will try again: [Get https://172.22.20.20:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-public/configmaps/cluster-info: dial tcp 172.22.20.20:6443: getsockopt: connection refused]
```

All worker nodes are built the exact same way (script) on Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Is there any limit for join?
What kind of logs would be useful?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. In my case, I was using vagrant to set up a private network.
When starting kubeadm, you must specify the host IP.

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr = 192.168.0.0 / 16 --apiserver-advertise-address = {Static_IP_ADRESS_HOST}
```

Example:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=172.16.94.10
```

the expected output will be something like
[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: This solved my problem. However I used the private IP in the master node not the host. `--apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.0.10`

Answer (score 4):

No, there are no limits for joining to the cluster.

You got `dial tcp 172.22.20.20:6443: getsockopt: connection refused`, which means that your new node cannot connect to the Kubernetes API server which is working on master.

Try to check your network connection between a new node and a master by `curl`, as example - `curl https://172.22.20.20:6443`, I think you will get a similar error.

So, check and repair your network settings, it should help.

Answer (score 0):

you can just go to the master node and edit inbound rules to add 6443 port and re-run kubeadm join on slave node .it should work this time